# Find and Delete a Folder when it has a specfic parent folder

Tags: shell, unix, find, directory

I'm trying to search and delete an old Backup of a program on a 4TB Disk. There may well be over 500 instances of it for various users, etc... The folder is called ACCOUNTS and it is located in /home/local/*/backups/Acc/ACCOUNTS where * is a username. The problem is that the most recent backups are located in /home/local/*/backups/Acc/Mon/ACCOUNTSfor 7 day rotations.

I can use find to find and delete all instances of ACCOUNTS but this will delete the ones I want to keep also.

So how would have search for a Folder called Accounts whos Parent folder is call Acc and delete it while leaving all other instances of ACCOUNTS intacted?

I tried `find /home/local/ -type d -name "Acc/ACCOUNTS" -exec rm -rf {} \;` but this will not work because it will think the the forward slash is part of the name and give a warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -r /home/local/*/backups/Acc/ACCOUNTS
```

should work. Or if you have a lot of accounts and the above hits `ARG_MAX`

```
for f in /home/local/*/backups/Acc/ACCOUNTS; do rm -r "$f"; done
```

You can test what it's going to delete by just doing `echo home/local/*/backups/Acc/ACCOUNTS`

If for some reason you want `find`, you can do a number of different things, probably simplest would be just to use `-regex`

```
find /home/local/ -type d -regex '.*/Acc/ACCOUNTS' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Replace `-exec rm -rf {} \;` with `-print` to test.